# Two times same monitor, 1x DVI, 1x HDMI => HDMI is blurred

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi, dvi

Since many many years I'm using two AOC 619fh monitors (they are quite old). I used them mostly together with a docking station with my laptop both were connected via DVI. They worked perfectly over all these years in 1920 x 1080.

However now my laptop broke and I decided to go for a computer again.

I bougth a mid-range computer, here are some of the important specs:

- Mainboard: Asus   PRIME H270M-PLUS
- Graphic card:     Asus nVidia GeForce GTX 1050Ti

This dedicated graphic card doesn't have two DVI ports anymore. Instead it has 1 x DVI, 1 x HDMI, 1 x Display Port.

I set the computer up with Windows 10 Professional, installed all updates.
Then I installed the newest NVIDIA driver:
[image]

It doesn't work correctly.
Both display are detected, the one I connected via DVI is working perfectly (as expected), the one connected via HDMI works but is not sharp, it's a little blurry.

What I tried so far:

- Reset monitor settings & played a little around with it
- Used a different HDMI calbe
- Used a HDMI to DisplayPort adapter
- Used a HDMI to DisplayPort cable
- Switched the cables of the displays (i.e. used DVI for the other monitor and vice versa)

All of this didn't change a thing it's still blurry.

Basically I'm out of ideas, any help is appreciated, just tell me if you need more information.

Here's also a picture, however I doubt that you can really see the problem:
[image]

Comment: have you tried connecting the monitor to Display port of the graphics card? What was the result?

Comment: Yes I tried it with a HDMI => Display Port cable, it was also blurry / not sharp.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I managed to find something.

If I go to the monitor settings and then to `Picture Boost` I changed the settings to that:

[image]

The important thing is the `Frame Size`.

I have no idea what I just did and why it works - maybe someone can lighten me up.

PS: On the DVI montior the `Bright Frame` is turned `off` which means all other settings are disabled.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue: As recommended by @tenhouse already had to set `Image Size` to `Auto`:
[image]